# How to Import/Export Power Automate flow with AI Builder Custom Model?

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online, power-automate, power-platform, power-automate-custom-connector

I have created Power Automate Flow with AI builder custom models to read data from PDF and add that data to SharePoint list in my office 365 tenant (For example: https://contoso.sharepoint.com/).

Now, I need to add that flow with AI builder custom model to another office 365 tenant (For example: https://contosonew.sharepoint.com/).

Can anyone help me with the same?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you not just export the model and import into the other tenant?

Comment: Thanks for response. Do I need to only export the model and import into the other tenant or both export the flow & model and import to another tenant?

Comment: Both, they're independent of each other.

Comment: Thanks for response. I have tried to export/import both flow & model. Facing some issues while import model in another tenant. I have take reference form Microsoft official site. Please suggest some good reference links if you have. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is to create a new solution > add your existing flow > add your published model and then export the solution

It's important to note that the model will be usable in the other tenant but can't be retrained.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

When you want to move more than one component (Power automate flow/Power app/AI model, etc.), it is recommended to use **Solutions** in Power platform.

You can create a power platform solution, add your power automate flow & AI builder model in solution, export the solution from one environment and import it in another environment/tenant.

Check below documentations for more information:

1. [Solutions overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/solutions-overview)
2. [Create a solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/create-solution)
3. [Export solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/export-solutions)
4. [Import solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/import-update-export-solutions)